# Object.type - Empty / Effector

Tags: python, objects

Is there a way to distinguish empties from effectors ?

If I have one empty and one force field, this :

```
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    print(obj.type)
```

will return :

> Empty
>   Empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty

```
is_empty = obj.type == 'EMPTY'
#or 
is_empty = obj.data is None
```

All objects have a field attribute, that is `'NONE'` if there is no force field assigned to it.

```
is_effector = obj.field.type != 'NONE'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's very clear. Does this mean that a force field can be assigned to any object ?